# Google Play Services Multiplayer matching players errors

Tags: google-play-services, multiplayer

I developed a game for android with the google play services realtime multiplayer feature. I currently have a problem when matching the players. I dont use any invite feature, so all players just use the automatch functionality.

My game can be played with 4 players, but games with just 3 or 2 players are also possible. For my testing with 2 devices i use:

```
RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(minNumberOfOpponents, maxNumberOfOpponents, 0);
```

If i keep starting, ending and restarting games for a number of times, it often happens that the clients are not connected correctly. In the working cases the games onRoomConnected is called correctly and the game starts. In some cases tho, this is not happening. In theses cases, one device finds the other device and its onPeerJoined() and onRoomConnecting() callback is called. onRoomConnected() is never called tho. Thats because the other device gets no information whatsoever, just the roomCreated callback is called, and thats it.

So one device finds the other, and gets the information that another device joined the room. It also gets informed when this device leaves the room again. But the other device doesnt recognize any of this.

If this helps. i had some issues with losing connection before, and fixed it by restarting the apiClient everytime a room left on any clint. I dont think this is related tho.

I thought that might be a problem with leaving the current room correctly, and somehow joining the old room again, but it also happens ehen starting the app for the first time. Also the apiClient reconnect should avoid this problem

Thx in advance

Edit: It seems like its just my nexus 5 which produces the error. Every other device i tested works fine. The Nexus 5 does too in most cases. If the clients get connected and the game starts, there has never been any problem. The errrr just happens on this one device, and only in maybe 5 out of 6 cases, when searching an online game.

It just stops getting any callbacks called, sometimes right after the onRoomCreated(), sometime after he found another peer and onRoomConnecting(), and sometimes after onRoomConnected() has been called.

The other device gets its appropiate callbacks called tho in these cases.

- So if the error device stops at onRoomCreated() the other device finds the client.
- If the error device finds the other device and gets onRoomConnecting() called and stops after, the other device gets its onRoomConnected().
- And if the error device gets its onRoomConnected() called, it sometimes even stops getting any messages from there on, while the other device is already in the game.

Comment: If i remember correctly, the problem had something to do with using different threads for the device logic and the online callbacks. If you have a similar issue, try to use the mainThread for everything inside the gps callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone. i'm not 100 % sure i fixed my problem. Haven't tested it in depth, but it seems everything is working fine now.

My problem was, that i have 2 different threads in my application, where the standard activity GUI thread starts the apiClient and handles the callbacks, while the gameengine thread initiates the room creation and sends the reliable messages via the apiClient.

It seems, sometimes things mess up while the peers connect and trade their first data. Currently i avoided directly calling any apiClient actions from the gameengine thread, but use runOnGuiThread to handle these actions on the Activity Gui Thread.